# How can I trigger KeyDown event with KeyCode in my AngularDart 5 test?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to trigger KeyDown event with specific key code in my test. I've found this example in `KeyEvent` documentation (into `html_dart2js.dart` file):

```
// Initialize a stream for the KeyEvents:
var stream = KeyEvent.keyPressEvent.forTarget(document.body);
// Add a new KeyEvent of someone pressing the 'A' key to the stream so
// listeners can know a KeyEvent happened.
stream.add(new KeyEvent('keypress', keyCode: 65, charCode: 97));
```

But it doesn't work because `stream` doesn't have `add` method.

I can do `document.dispatchEvent` but it doesn't allow to send key code:

```
document.dispatchEvent(KeyboardEvent('keydown'));
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the KeyEvent class from dart:html something like this:

```
dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(event,
              keyCode: keyCode,
              charCode: charCode,
              altKey: altKey,
              ctrlKey: ctrlKey,
              metaKey: metaKey,
              shiftKey: shiftKey)
          .wrapped)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have not found any information about `.wrapped` before.